# Renaming multiple columns using a column index

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

Here is my example data.frame

```
df <- tibble(
    ID = 1:3,
    col_x = LETTERS[1:3],
    col_q = letters[1:3],
    col_w = 3:1
)

> df
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID col_x col_q col_w
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     1 A     a         3
2     2 B     b         2
3     3 C     c         1
```

I want to rename all columns except the ID column by appending the column index (excluding the ID column).  Desired output:

```
     ID col_x1 col_q2 col_w3
  <int> <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1     1 A      a           3
2     2 B      b           2
3     3 C      c           1
```

(I will remove the original `x`, `q`, `w` in a subsequent step).  I've tried:

```
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(.x, 1), .cols = -ID)               # Works
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(.x, col_number()), .cols = -ID)    # Does nothing
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(.x, col_number()-1), .cols = -ID)  # Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It has just occurred to me while writing this that `col_number()` comes from `readr` unlike `row_number()` which comes from `dplyr` - so I was expecting `col_number()` to behave like `row_number()`.  Given that, how can I achieve this without having to spell out each key pair in `rename`, e.g. `rename(col_x1 = col_x, col_q2 = col_q, col_w3 = col_w)`?

**EDIT**:

`df %>% rename_with(~paste0(.x, 1:3), .cols = -ID)` achieves what I want, but the number of columns is not fixed (may be many more than 3), hence needing a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rename_with(\(x) paste0(x, seq_along(x)), -ID)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID col_x1 col_q2 col_w3
  <int> <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1     1 A      a           3
2     2 B      b           2
3     3 C      c           1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had not considered `seq_along`.  Great use for it.  Can you explain the `\(x)` part? I have not seen this before.  `df %>% rename_with( ~ paste0(.x, seq_along(.x)), -ID)` also works, which I'm more familiar with.

Comment: `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)` and was introduced to R a couple of years ago.  It's the base equivalent to the `purrr`-style lamba function you're familiar with.